# How to horizontally center div classes in @media and across browsers?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have several div classes that I'd like to center in @media. Tried the following, with and without `margin-left`. One is an animation which seems to behave strangely when moved or adjusted.

Css:

```
 @media(min-width: 768px) {.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {margin: 
 auto !important; margin-left:50% !important;}}

 @media (max-width: 5000px) and (min-width: 768px) 
{.contact::before, 
.contact::after {margin: auto !important; margin-left: 50% 
!important;}} 

@media (max-width: 5000px) and (min-width: 768px) {.wpcf7 
{margin:auto! important; margin-left :50% !important;}}

@media (max-width: 5000px) and (min-width: 768px) 
{#anr_captcha_field_1 {margin: auto !important; margin-left: 50% 
!important;

}}
```

I always thought that `margin: auto` would work but it doesn't seem to, even with `important`

https://adsler.co.uk/contact-us/

```
></p>
<p><label> Subject<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control- 
wrap your-subject"><input  
type="text" name="your-subject" 
value="" size="40" class="wpcf7- 
form-control wpcf7-text" aria- 
invalid="false" /></span> </label>. 
 </p>
<p><label> Your Message<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control- 
wrap your-message"><textarea 
name="your-message" cols="40" 
rows="10" 
class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7- 
textarea" aria-invalid="false">. 
</textarea></span> </label></p>
<p><div class="anr_captcha_field">. 
<div 
id="anr_captcha_field_1" 
class="anr_captcha_field_div">. 
</div></div><span class="wpcf7- 
form-control-wrap g-recaptcha- 
response"></span></p>
<p><input type="submit" 
value="Send" class="wpcf7-form- 
control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output 
wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>. 
</div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Yes sir, html comin right up...

Answer (score 0):

You can center the content of the div with flexbox. Try this:

```
.myClass {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Also, remove that margin props.

- Explanation: the margin prop did not worked because maybe the width of the div was 100% of the device width. So you need to handle the content. Flexbox is a great tool to do that.
- I leave you useful links to learn more about [flexbox](https://cssreference.io/flexbox/) and [box-model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp), that is the core concept about this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. I'll let you know the effects because I'm currently mobile.

Comment: You are welcome. I just improved my answer for more clarity.